# Create a page in order to update only two columns of the table aspnetusers

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I added Firstname and Lastname in the registration form but I do not know ho to add a new page (view) in "AREAS / IDENTITY / PAGES" with a form in order to update just the 2 fields

```
postalcode
address
```

Where is the controller which allow me to add a view in this folder?
And what to do in order to add 2 new fields which will be updated in this new page?

HERE MY CODE with the two field firstname and last name :

in the input model inside the public class InputModel of the register cs

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "The First Name must be max 255 characters long.")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "The Last Name must be max 255 characters long.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

fields in the register page view

```
<div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" autocomplete="firstname" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" autocomplete="lastname" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.LastName"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

field to the crationuser in the register cs inside the

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
under the var user = CreateUser();

user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
user.LastName = Input.LastName;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is "Scaffold Identity Pages".

1. You need to install the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`.
2. After installing, Right click on the Controller folder > Add > New Scaffolded item > Identity > Click Add
3. Click the checkbox "Override all files"
4. Data Context Class: Choose your Db Context Class
5. Click Add / Submit

You will need to do the same for the Views Folder so that the Identity Views will be generated.

After generating, you can now modify the views and controller to use your Custom identity user.

Comment: The whole subject is here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Hi Jerdine, i already done this, and i already costomize my identity model in order to have firstname and lastname in the registration page, what i wish  to accomplish is to create a new page (view) called "Yourplace.chstml" where i update the 2 new field, how to do this?

Comment: @TamilCantroz please include your custom identity class code in the question

Comment: Hi , i just added the code for the 2 field